# Best way speak/write setting a profile picture

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

What's the best way to speak/write that someone has made his profile picture with french flag?

- > He changed his profile picture with french flag
- > He made his profile picture with french flag

or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction I believe to be the smoothest is:

> He has put the French flag on his profile picture.

"put something on" in this case has the meaning of "use something as", but I'd rather not choose the latter, because it would look like I'm literally taking the french flag, while the first has a more neutral meaning.

As of your suggestions:

- > He changed his profile picture with french flag

  it could be fixed by changing  *with* to *to*, though sounds... too plain and can be confusing, for it reads as: *I've removed the profile picture and put the french flag instead* (ridiculous, isn't it?)
- > He made his profile picture with french flag

  just the wrong verb. The only fix I've thought of is replacing *with* with *of*, then the meaning would be: *He took the french flag, broke / disassembled it and created the profile picture of its parts.* (also doesn't make much sense)

Comment: What would be  best speaking  form?

Comment: @Sabbir no idea on the best variants, just tried to express it smoothly.